# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'form' referenced before assignment in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

So I'm working on a Django project and this is my `views.py` file:

```
def new_topic(request, pk):
    board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=pk)
    user = User.objects.first()  # TODO: get the currently logged in user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewTopicForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        topic = form.save()
        return redirect('board_topics', pk=board.pk)
    else:
        form = NewTopicForm()
    return render(request, 'new_topic.html', {'form': form})
```

When I ran my server, I got an error saying:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'form' referenced before assignment`

This is my `new_topic.html` file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Start a New Topic{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Boards</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'board_topics' board.pk %}">{{ board.name }}</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">New topic</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Post</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Note that Django made a reference to this line: if form.is_valid():

Answer (score 4):

The line `if form.is_valid():` fails on a `GET` request, because you're only defining `form` when `request.method == 'POST'`.

This can be fixed by changing some indentation:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NewTopicForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        topic = form.save()
        return redirect('board_topics', pk=board.pk)
else:
    form = NewTopicForm()
return render(request, 'new_topic.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any issue with indentation, but with initialization. Kindly initialize for before rendering it! Make changes as shown below will definitely work out and it's a very genuine and proper way to get rid of it:

```
def new_topic(request, pk):
    board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=pk)
    user = User.objects.first()  # TODO: get the currently logged in user
    form = NewTopicForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewTopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           topic = form.save()
           return redirect('board_topics', pk=board.pk)
        else:
            form = NewTopicForm()
    return render(request, 'new_topic.html', {'form': form})
```